# Running time of a nested for loop

Tags: algorithm, analysis

1a.)The loop is below and I want to find it's running time. Here is the loop

```
sum = 0
for (int i =0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
          sum ++
```

The first for loops runs in O(n) which is easy, however for the 2nd I think it also runs in O(n) time because whenever `j = i`, this loop will run i times.

So I wrote down this has a running time of O(n^2).

1b. )Moreover, can someone also explain what is meant, when a problems asks for a "theta bound"?

Comment: Homework question! Read your textbook.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's pretty simple to work out the exact number of loop iterations here. You get 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + ... + N.

That sums to N(N+1) / 2, so yes, the algorithmic complexity is O(N<sup>2</sup>).

I can't say I've come across theta bounds... the [Wikipedia page on big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) mentions it though, so that might be a reasonable *starting* point.

Comment: So the inner loop's number of iteration is also the number of iterations of the outer loop correct?

Comment: @user373466: No, the outer loop is only executing N times... but it's not doing any extra work.

Answer (score 3):

Theta bound means that it is a tight asymptotic bound, that bounds the running time both from above and below. In your example, N^2 is both a lower and upper bound on the running time, and hence it is a theta bound on the running time.

More formally:

there exists k1 and k2 such that:

N^2 * k1 <= N(N+1)/2 <= N^2 * k2

for N > some value N0.

Ps. This book gives a pretty good explanation of the different asymptotic bounds: [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Third-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262033844/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1295777605&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Answer (score 1):

`f(n) = O(g(n))` if and only if for big enough `n` there exists a constant `c` such that `f(n) <= c*g(n)`. Basically, big-O notation gives you an upper bound. You could just as well say your program runs in `O(n^3)`, `O(n^2011)` and even `O(n^42142342)`, but these wouldn't be of much help to you, would they?

Theta notation gives you a **tight** bound, which is a lot more helpful. `f(n) = Theta(g(n))` if and only if for big enough `n` there exists constants `c1, c2` such that `c1*g(n) <= f(n) <= c2*g(n)`, which means that you know the exact function your algorithm is proportional to.

Your algorithm does `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N` operations, which sums up to `N(N+1)/2`. This is `Theta(N^2)` because `N^2/4 + N/4 <= N^2/2 + N/2 <= N^2 + N`. So you can take `c1` and `c2` in the above definition to be `1/2` and `2`.

Most of the time people will use big-O notation to express a tight bound, but this is not necessary. There are always multiple answers when asked for the big-O of a function, but only one answer when asked for the theta bound.

Comment: Your big-O definition is unclear. It reads as though the constant `c` can depend upon `n`. Should be "... iff there exists `N` and `c` such that for all `n > N` ..."

Comment: @Chris Hopman - if it's a constant, I think it's obvious that it cannot depend on `n`, which is a variable. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: so the answer, to the question "find the theta bound" would be 0.5(n^2) =< (n^2) =< 2(n^2) ? for n greater or equal to zero?

Comment: @user373466 - no, the answer to that question is `Theta(n^2)`. That is just how you'd get to the answer.